# Set timer for blinking text

Tags: java, android, xml, blink

i want my text to blink but it should be displayed for 5 seconds and invisible for 2 seconds.
How do i manage that?

Currently the text is visible as long as inivisible.

**test.xml**

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_WorkingNFC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Halte bitte dein Armband an die Rückseite des Gerätes."
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**test.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_access_control);
        blinking();
    }

    private void blinking() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int timeToBlink = 1000;
                try{Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch (Exception e) {}
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.textView_WorkingNFC);
                        if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        blinking();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend using a daemon thread, otherwise, the moment you call that thread, the rest of your application is blocked

Comment: @Stultuske ty very much, how can i do that?

Comment: My Solution `if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }` but how can I do that with daemon thread?